# Why does emacs intermittantly not use the alternate screen?

Tags: terminal, emacs

I use emacs with the -nw flag so that it runs in the terminal.  I don't run it inside screen or tmux or anything like that, just a plain terminal.  Often when I exit emacs I return to a view of my terminal that shows the emacs command I typed but no longer shows the file I was editing or the emacs menu bar or anything like that.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979318/how-to-avoid-emacs-or-vi-remaining-on-your-screen-after-closing-when-using-gnu) I take it that this behavior is because emacs uses a so called "alternate screen" in my terminal.  This is the behavior I want.

Maybe 30% of the time when I exit emacs the file I was editing and the menu bar and such are still on the screen.  Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script) I tried the hacky solution of aliasing emacs to "tput smcup; emacs -nw".  That seemed to reduce the frequency of the problem down to maybe 5 or 10%, but it didn't fix it and I'm sure it's not the "right" thing to do anyway.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this has been resolved for Emacs 29.  Refer to the [NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS?h=master&id=ee0848171262f7fc693b18e4bf04e9f9c98d1e88#n93).